# TYPO3 extension Model conflict with f:form.upload

Tags: typo3-extensions

For an own extension, I want o use the viewhelper `f:form.upload`
to retrieve the upload parameters I have to define the property for this viewhelper as an array. These work fine to get the name, type, tmp_name, error, and size parameters.
In the Domain Model, I read the parameters and save the uploaded file and store the file name inside the database. That works fine! Here the part of the Domain Modell for the variable iFile:

```
/**
 * iFile
 * 
 * @var array
 * @TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Annotation\ORM\Cascade("remove")
 */
protected $iFile = [];

/**
 * Returns the iFile
 * 
 * @return string iFile
 */
public function getIFile()
{
    $temp = [];
$temp['image_name'] = $this->iFile;
    error_log("Get_iFile: " . var_export($temp, true), 0);
    error_log("Get_iFile0: " .  var_export($this, true), 0);
    return $temp;
}

/**
 * Sets the iFile
 * 
 * @param string $iFile
 * @return void
 */
public function setIFile($iFile)
{
    if($iFile['tmp_name'] != ""){
        $docRoot = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'\\' ;
        if (!is_dir($docRoot)) {
            mkdir($docRoot, 07777, true);
        }
        $date = new \DateTime();
        $fName = 'fileadmin\\Radio\\crNews\\' . $date->format('Ymd') . $iFile['name'];
        if(copy($iFile['tmp_name'], $docRoot . $fName) == true);
            unlink($iFile['tmp_name']);
    }
    error_log("Set _FILES: " . var_export($iFile, true), 0);
    $this->iFile = $fName;
}
```

But if I try to read it from the database, I don't get back the file name from the database! Only an empty array.

```
   'iFile' => 
   array (
   ),
```

The problem seems to be, due to the definition of iFile as an array.
How can I solve the problem?

Is there any possibility, to add a new variable to the Model as an array, but not to store it in the database?

Answer (score 0):

So I found a workaround. I only defined iFile as an string to read and save the file name in the database and used the $_FILES post variables to retrieve the name and tmp_name of the $_FILES.
In Typo3, access the $_FILES parameters is not so easy. So I recommend to use phpinstruction `error_log("Create _FILES: " . var_export($_FILES, true), 0);` to find out the structure of the array.